# shim.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < - Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular

Good day Folks,
I included shim.min.js as per this  [link here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html). This was needed in order to be able to support IE 11. But now i am getting the strange error:
[image]
Can some one help me to understand this error please.

This is how I included as per below:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>At2</title>
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/core-
 js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <body>

<app-root>Loading...</app-root>
```

See my node server:

```
  let express = require("express");
  var path = require('path');
  let app = require('express')();
  let http = require('http').Server(app);

  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



   // // Parsers for POST data
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));



  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
   });




   const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
   app.set('port', port);

   http.listen(port, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
 });
```

Comment: how are you including shim in your html? can you paste this ?

Comment: see above in post.. i pasted in the original.

Comment: I was mad yesterday with this same Syntax Error < after Angular4 migrated  Check for duplicate files. Anyways I recommend to you read this because there are a little good info about some related errors and links to solutions. Also could be there some code you can use. Too expand the error and read and try to debug on other browser to check what it says exactly. Is the way I have found what was going wrong. I went to angular support because I thought it was a bug and then I saw it was just my error.. A little weird XD Good luck! Here if I can help.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/43431500/7733724

Comment: i dont get any info on error..... just this empty message and cant expand... its angular cli project. And error doesnt occur if i run it ng serve.. only if build it and run it on node server...

Comment: Hmm.. Check for sure you have no one duplicated file. I had a duplicated file at the end (system.config.js). I was not linking it but anyways was the reason of my error because compiler was including it.

Comment: This is **almost always** due to a server misconfiguration, where the server is sending an HTML document (usually index.html) rather than the actual resource file.  Please post more information about the server configuration.

Comment: see server in original..pls

Comment: @Sam , what do you mean by checking duplicate.. which duplicate file?

Comment: Any duplicate files that may have been left that may be creating conflict. In your case it is rarer than mine cause mine was related to SystemJS (error said). I recommend you check packages.json, delete the folder node_modules and run npm cache clean. Then make a clean installation of all packages.